# Is the PCRE library thread-safe? If not, which do you recommend?

Tags: c++, regex, thread-safety, pcre

For C/C++, is the [PCRE](http://pcre.org/) library thread-safe?
If PCRE is thread-safe, is there any problem in performance?

Answer (score 2):

Judging from the [PCRE](http://pcre.org/pcre.txt) documentation:

> MULTITHREADING
>
> The  PCRE  functions  can be used in multi-threading applications, with
>          the  proviso  that  the  memory  management  functions  pointed  to  by
>          pcre_malloc, pcre_free, pcre_stack_malloc, and pcre_stack_free, and the
>          callout and stack-checking functions pointed  to  by  pcre_callout  and
>          pcre_stack_guard, are shared by all threads.
>
> The  compiled form of a regular expression is not altered during matching, so the same compiled pattern can safely be used by several threads
>          at once.
>
> If  the just-in-time optimization feature is being used, it needs separate memory stack areas for each thread. See the pcrejit  documentation
>          for more details.

All of this means that if you are careful, the answer is 'Yes, the PCRE library is thread-safe'.

Comment: thx very much. I am using 7.8 version so there is no JIT optimization and it is totally thread-safe.

Comment: @chenming the JIT is thread-safe too if you let it use the thread's stack (which it does by default). Also, in version 10 the API has been massively revamped, and for instance you now have one callout handler per match context, not a single shared callout handler for the whole lib like in previous versions.

Answer (score 0):

Little off-topic, but I recommend to have a look at [RE2](https://code.google.com/p/re2/) (RE2 is thread-friendly)

Comment: RE2 is a DFA regex engine. PCRE is NFA (but DFA is available too). **Totally** different beasts.