# Is System.RegularExpressions.TRegEx thread-safe?

Tags: regex, multithreading, delphi, thread-safety, pcre

*Background*: An application that I came across uses a `TRegEx` singleton from within several threads. The singleton is initialized to `TRegEx.Create(Pattern, [roCompiled])` in a class constructor and the threads use it starting with `RegEx.Match(Value).Groups`, and there appears to be no synchronization mechanism employed, however, the application runs fine. Though, this is just a small part of the `TThread.Execute` override and there is little load on the threads. So this always might have worked just by chance, as the threads are unlikely to cross one another on the critical part.

*Thoughts*: On the one hand, thinking about it, it would make sense that a `TRegEx` instance would only hold an immutable (compiled) pattern and work on parameter input directly, or keep this input around in (`TMatch`) return values for a possible later continuation -- like with `NextMatch`, for example, which is implemented on `TMatch` and not on `TRegEx`. And [the underlying open source PCRE library seems to be thread-safe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28769170/2212557). All this fits the scenario above. On the other hand, I think a `TRegEx` instance is generally not thread-safe because, for example, in the `function TRegEx.Match(const Input: String): TMatch` (as used above) it looks like the string to be matched against the pattern is first stored to the instance before being matched. And the same nested `TPerlRegEx` instance is passed on and kept alive throughout various function chains. A shared `TRegEx` instance would seemingly need to be protected from uncoordinated access, with a critical section, for example.

That said, I suspect that [TRegEx](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.RegularExpressions.TRegEx) is not thread-safe, but I would like to ask someone knowledgeable at multithreading and at adjudicating thread-safety for confirmation. Hence, my question -- very much general and independent from the application from which it evolved:

*Question*: Is TRegEx thread-safe?

Comment: A *class constructor* is run only once, during unit initialization. So anything it initializes will be accessible to all threads that use the unit.  So it should be safe for multiple threads to share `FRegEx`. What are you suspecting is not thread-safe exactly? Can you provide an example?

Comment: @Remy, I have added an explanation with example where `TRegEx` is not thread-safe, I think.

Comment: Why can't you show the example directly rather than an excerpt?

Comment: @David and @Remy?, this is about TRegEx, not the application that made me ask. I am afraid the background information I gave distracted from this. And as far as Delphi-provided code is concerned, I am unsure of what exactly and how much to quote for this question, and I do not feel comfortable in judging the line between quoting and copying -- especially when StackOverflow will persist my decision in a revision, well, forever? However, the lines I am referring to are just a Ctrl-click on `Match` away: `RegEx.Match(‘’)`. On this one I perhaps should have mentioned my Delphi version: 10.2 it is.

Comment: I would think an example of code that might fail if the part of TRegEx you think might not be thread safe is in fact not thread safe. Otherwise the question is a bit open ended.

Comment: I think it is a yes-no question, however, I do not mean to imply it is easy to assess. In fact, I would not have asked if I had not found the underlying library to be thread-safe, which I consider hard to do, and if my thoughts on the interface had not made sense. Obviously, I hope for a yes, but I also tried to find and back up a no. In the end, I do not feel knowledgeable enough. That said, I do not want to debug an application but to reach an answer of wider use, and for more people. And maybe someone notices most work is done, and maybe will lift thread-safety to `TRegEx`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PCRE library on which Delphi's regex class is built is threadsafe. See [PCRE pcre_exec thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38928867/pcre-pcre-exec-thread-safe)

However, the Delphi wrapper `TRegex` is not threadsafe. Consider the calls made to `pcre_exec` in `TPerlRegEx.Match`:

```
OffsetCount := pcre_exec(FPattern, FHints, @FSubject[0], FStop, 0, Opts, @Offsets[0],
  High(Offsets));
```

Here `FSubject` and `Offsets` are members of `TPerlRegEx` and so will be shared between different threads using this instance of `TPerlRegEx`, which in turn is owned by the instance of `TRegEx`.

For `TRegEx` to be threadsafe in the sense that you desire (multiple threads performing matches on a shared compiled regex) these variables would need to be private to each invocation of a match function.